# Symbolic machine instruction,Pseudo instruction difference

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mips64

What is the difference between Symbolic machine instruction and Pseudo instruction?

For example are

`li $t0,5`

`addi $t5,$t3,2`

`move $a0,$t0`

symbolic machine instructions are pseudo instructions? Can you give examples of them?

Comment: `li` and `move` are pseudo-instructions. I don't think I've ever heard the term "symbolic machine instruction" before so you'll have to define exactly what that means.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo instructions are the instructions which assembler cannot convert it to the machine code (ones and zeros) directly. In order to do that, assembler first translates the one lined pseudo instruction into a combination of the symbolic machine instructions. Then converts it to the machine code.